# Load product based on week number

Tags: magento

Hi im trying to load a collection of products based on a release date.

i have the date in a attribute on all products an i want to show these products that has a release date in the current week. 
Here is what i got so far

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('film_format', 7 )
    ->addAttributeToFilter('film_releasedatum', array('eq' => date("o-W", strtotime("W"))))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', 14 )
    ->setOrder('film_releasedatum','DESC')
    ->load();
```

I hope some one can share some light on this

Comment: You forgot to tell us, what problem you're facing. Besides that it would be helpful if you post some valid sample values of your `film_releasedatum` field. According to "o-W" it should be s/t like "2013-42", but only you know what data this attribute really contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i can give you alternate filter attribute that will sure work for you

**create start and end date for current week**

```
$date = time(); // Change to whatever date you need
$dotw = $dotw = date('w', $date);
$end = ($dotw == 5 /* Friday */) ? $date : strtotime('next Friday', $date);
$start = $end - (6 * 24*60*60);
$start = date('Y-m-d',$start);
$end = date('Y-m-d',$end);
```

Add below two filter to your collection

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('film_releasedatum', array('gteq' =>$start));
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('film_releasedatum', array('lteq' => $end));
```

final filter would look like

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('film_format', 7 )
    ->addAttributeToFilter('film_releasedatum', array('gteq' =>$start))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('film_releasedatum', array('lteq' =>$end))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', 14 )
    ->setOrder('film_releasedatum','DESC')
    ->load();
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: @Martin Alderlöf,glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a special condition for date to select record. Please try to change with that.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('film_format', 7 )
->addAttributeToFilter('film_releasedatum', array('gteq' =>$start))
->addAttributeToFilter('film_releasedatum', array('lteq' =>$end))
->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', 14 )
->setOrder('film_releasedatum','DESC')
->load();
```

To.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('film_format', 7 )
->addAttributeToFilter('film_releasedatum', array(
    'from' => $first,
    'to' => $end,
    'date' => true,
    ))
->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', 14 )
->setOrder('film_releasedatum','DESC')
->load();
```

Comment: pls dont add more condition to each attribute and also please find way to do best and dont theft any idea from other answer.